# How to sum two arrays without repeating the same values

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays which i dont know how sum itself. For examples:

```
[1,2,3]+[2,3,4,5]=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way is to perform a [set union](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-7C):

```
[1,2,3,4] | [1,2,5,6] #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Unlike `(array1 + array2).uniq`, this performs the operation in one step rather than two.

Comment: it's interesting to me that `set union` is optimized two ways, one for smaller arrays by doing two loops and the other way by creating a hash and then dumping the values.  I would have thought `Set.new(array1 + array2)` would have similar performance but it is 4x slower - very interesting!

Comment: @Anthony `Array#|` is written in C whereas `Set` is implemented in Ruby.